# Network Connections - able to connect to wireless but network connections does not display my connection

Tags: 11.10, wireless, networking

Im using Ubuntu Oneiric and AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter.

I can connect to my wireless network without problem. However when I click the "Network Connection" icon on system tray, it is disabled and it says "Wireless Network device not managed".

When I checked it on terminal using "iwconfig wlan0", it seems ok.

```
wlan0 IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"dd-wrt"  
Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 00:22:6B:58:E6:D0   
Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
Power Management:off
Link Quality=69/70  Signal level=-41 dBm  
Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:445   Missed beacon:0
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by editing NetworkManager configuration file.

Edit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and it should look like this:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

*credit goes to http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9402242*

However, when I reboot my machine, on startup screen it shows "Waiting for network connection" for a few seconds (which will take more time to boot). The only workaround for now is to [replace lightdm with gdm](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1844819&page=2).

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to remove the lines associated with the wireless interface from /etc/network/interfaces, and then reboot:

```
sudo sensible-editor /etc/network/interfaces
```

If you aren't sure which interface that is, try

```
iwconfig
```

and look for the lines with ESSID, indicating that they are a wireless interface.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by installing 'dhcpcd'

```
$ apt-get install dhcpcd
```